# keeping values after redirecting in google app engine python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, web

I have just started learning web development using GAE and I have the following question. Isn't there any way to post data to the webpage after redirecting. I want input values to be kept after redirecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way that you can do this is by including the information in your html template

```
<form action="" method="post"> 
  <input type="hidden" name="passedValue" value = {{value}}>
</form>
```

Put the value that you want to be passed in {{value}} (add more inputs if necessary). So when you redirect, each page will store the value of the previous page, but you will need to add code to your main.py to sub the values into the html template through jinja as well.

Another way that I could suggest would be just storing the information in Datastore and then retrieving it at the final destination